# Beta logo still present on Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: bug, design

It looks like the new logo didn't make it to the SE app?

[image: iOS old logo]

Comment: Blame caching. Or Apple. The Android app looks fine here ;-)

Comment: Probably a caching issue. I had the old logo persist for a few days, but I have the new one now.

Comment: Gotta be a coaching issue. I have the iOS app and the new logo is there. It's washed out and barely visible, but there.